# Consistently separate values in array

Tags: ruby, arrays, regex, string

After uploading a file I put each line of the file into an array. 
I want to only save a part of the array, here is an example of the array...

```
[ "1, \"Hlavní\"\n", "2, OK\n", "3618, \"Duplicitní záznamy\"\n", "3619, \"Anyth1ng_ Go@es /n th7s'me??\"\n" ]
```

I want to trim the strings down to...

```
[ "Hlavní", "OK", "Duplicitní záznamy", "Anyth1ng_ Go@es /n th7s'me??" ]
```

The one thing I can be certain of is its always between a `\"` and `\"` or  `,` and `\n`, I have tried grabbing the text but don't know how to get it so precise.

Here is one file uploaded:

```
#INDEX  STRING
0, "Deutsch"
# Main
1, "Hauptmenü"
2, "Sonstiges"
3, "Kontrolle"
4, "Datei Ansicht"
5, "Laden..."
6, "Registriert"
7, "Nicht registriert"
8, "Ja"
9, "Nein"
10, "Anrufen"
11, "Suchen"
12, "Neu"
13, "Bearbeiten"
14, "Löschen"
15, "Alle löschen"
16, "Zurück"
17, "Zurück zum Hauptverzeichnis"
18, "Optionen"
19, "Speichern"
```

And another

```
#Comment 1-500
1, Ende
2, OK
3, Abbrechen
4, Senden
5, Ja
6, Nein
7, Ein
8, Aus
9, Start
10, Stopp
11, Pause
12, Standard
13, Alle
14, Titel
15, Benutzerdefinierte Sprache

#Call 501-999
501, Telefon
503, Wählen...
504,
```

Comment: It looks like you better show us the string/line that you had before you converted them into an array. We can probably show a straightforward answer than converting the array that you have. In other words, this is probably an XY-question.

Comment: @sawa Okay It is a file attachment with Paperclip. How do you want to show it? I can open it anyway cant I?

Comment: If it's a CSV file why not just use a CSV library? CSV is a bit of a PITA; try to pull it apart with regex--"now you have two problems".

Comment: Its a plain/text file, I'll post the code Im using to open it

Comment: Looks like CSV to me, although each line is just two values. Not sure why you couldn't just strip everything up to and including the first comma, either; what do you need regex for?

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't need regex. I thought it would work. Your comma suggestion seems right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one option:

```
arr = [ "1, \"Hlavní\"\n",
        "2, OK\n",
        "3618, \"Duplicitní záznamy\"\n",
        "3619, \"Anyth1ng_ Go@es /n th7s'me??\"\n" ]

r = /,\s+"\K.+?(?=")|,\s+\K.+?(?=\n)/    
arr.map { |s| s[r] }
  #=> ["Hlavní", "OK", "Duplicitní záznamy", "Anyth1ng_ Go@es /n th7s'me??"]
```

I've required the string to be preceded by either `, \"` or by `,`. The former is somewhat stronger than the specified match requirement; if inappropriate, it can be weakened in the obvious way. I used `\K` (match what comes before but do not include in the match) rather than a positive lookbehind to allow for the possibility of varying amounts of whitespace after the comma.

Let's take a closer look at the regex. By adding the `x` ("extended") at the end we can string it out over several commented lines:

```
r = /
  ,\s+   # match a comma followed by one or more whitespace chars
  "      # match `"`
  \K     # forget what has been matched previously
  .+?    # match any number of any character, lazily
  (?=")  # match must be immediately followed by `"` (positive lookahead)
  |      # match what has been matched so far or is matched later ("or")
  ,\s+   # as above
  \K     # as above
  .+?    # as above
  (?=\n) # match to be immediately followed by `\n` (positive lookahead)
/x
```

Let's confirm the regex can be written this way:

```
arr.map { |s| s[r] }
  #=> ["Hlavní", "OK", "Duplicitní záznamy", "Anyth1ng_ Go@es /n th7s'me??"]
```

Note:

- `?` following `.+` makes the match lazy ("non-greedy") so that it will stop when the following element of the match (`"` or `\n`) is found, rather than gobbling up everything until it finds the last `"` or `\n` in the string;
- the two positive lookaheads are "zero-width", meaning they do not consume characters are not part of the match.

This could alternatively be written:

```
arr.map { |s| s[/,\s+\K(?:"\K.+?(?=")|.+?(?=\n))/] }
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please elaborate with a small example.

Comment: I was asking if you could explain your expression in a couple sentences.

Comment: Your explanation is very helpful, so is this ruby link, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
[ "1, \"Hlavní\"\n", "2, OK\n", "3618, \"Duplicitní záznamy\"\n", "3619, \"Anyth1ng_ Go@es /n th7s'me??\"\n" ]
.map{|s| s[/(?<=")[^"]*(?=")/]}
# => ["Hlavní", nil, "Duplicitní záznamy", "Anyth1ng_ Go@es /n th7s'me??"]
```

Note that the second element in the result is `nil` as per your request (extracting the element between a `\"` and `\"`).

Comment: This works for \". Do you know how to get the text from "2, OK\n"  ?  ', ' and '\n'

Comment: I thought you wrote that the elements are between `\"`.

Comment: Yeah the one file, but the other ones don't put quotes. So it looks like the other has a ', ' on the left and '\n' on the right of the string.

Comment: Still got plus 1, can't ignore the better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the selected answer is not the best, here a better one.

```
@upload = File.new(@request.attachment.path)
@messages = File.read(@upload).scan(/\s+"?([^"\n]*)(?:"|\n)/).flatten
```

Comment: What you suggest may be satisfactory, but the question indicates that It should not match on `"2, OK\""`, yet `"2, OK\"".scan(/,\s* "?([^"\n]*)(?:"|\n)/).flatten #=> ["OK"] `.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I do not see this in the question.

Comment: I believe 'it is always between a `\"` and `\"` or  `,` and `\n`' means 'it is always between either 1) `\"` and `\"` or 2) `,` and `\n`', but your interpretation may be correct, and if not correct, it may be satisfactory, or possibly an improvement.