# Ruby advanced gsub

Tags: ruby, string, gsub

I've got a string like this one below:

```
My first <a href="http://google.com">LINK</a>
and my second <a href="http://yahoo.com">LINK</a>
```

How do I substitute all the links in this string from href="URL" to href="/redirect?url=URL" so that it becomes

```
My first <a href="/redirect?url=http://google.com">LINK</a>
and my second <a href="/redirect?url=http://yahoo.com">LINK</a>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your case we can construct following regex:

```
re = /
  href=       # Match attribute we are looking for
  [\'"]?      # Optionally match opening single or double quote
  \K          # Forget previous matches, as we dont really need it
  ([^\'" >]+) # Capture group of characters except quotes, space and close bracket
/x
```

Now you can replace captured group with string you need (use `\1` to refer a group):

```
str.gsub(re, '/redirect?url=\1')
```

Comment: Don't you think you owe the OP an explanation of the regex? I suggest you write it multiline `r = /.../x`, so that you can include comments, then `str.gsub(r)`.  My answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216618/consistently-separate-values-in-array/29218517#29218517) gives an example.

Comment: @CarySwoveland My bad, added an explanation.

Comment: You are forgiven, this time.

Answer (score 1):

`gsub` allows you to match regex patterns and use captured substrings in the substitution:

```
x = <<-EOS
My first <a href="http://google.com">LINK</a>
and my second <a href="http://yahoo.com">LINK</a>
EOS

x.gsub(/"(.*)"/, '"/redirect?url=\1"') # the \1 refers to the stuff captured 
                                       # by the (.*)
```

Comment: Thanks Amit but this doesn't solve the problem as I might have other words in the string containing double quotes..

Comment: What other unstated constraints does your question have?  You should add them to your original question.

Comment: Sorry Amit, what do you mean with constraints? It's a simple string with links from a database. Nothing more...

Comment: Manuel, `puts x.gsub(/"(.*)"/, '"/redirect?url=\1"') #=> "My first...LINK</a> and my second...LINK</a>"`, which is the result you asked for. Amit is assuming that, by your comment, you mean the same result is required if `"cat's have nine lives"`.` were tacked onto the end of the string. The question does not give that as a requirement, so he wants the question to be more precise.